# Let the server own the file created by the client on a Samba share

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

I'm sharing a directory on my Mac using Samba. When the client (Raspebian) creates a file on the mounted share, the file is owned by the user on the client and the permissions are set to -rw-------.
Is it possible to have the user on the server own the file? If not, how do I make newly created files have different permissions?

My fstab looks like this:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, so no using swapon|off from here on, use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
/dev/sda1       /mnt/tm         auto    defaults        0       0
/dev/sda2       /mnt/data       auto    defaults        0       0
//mbp/Downloaded        /mnt/downloaded cifs    defaults,user=usr,password=xxxx,uid=usr,gid=usr,nosetuids,rw,nounix,sec=ntlmssp      0       0
```

P.S. the last two options are apparently necessary for mounting shares from OS X. I couldn't mount without them.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: oh, I'm sorry, this might not apply to Mac, I use it on Linux.

These can be set in smb.conf on the server.

I think what you are looking for is **force user**; **create mask**, **force create mode** and their directory creating counterparts. **inherit owner** and **inherit permissions** can be useful too.